# How can I upgrade a gateway?

Tags: stellaris

I've researched the Gateway tech, but I can't use the existing gateways - neither science ships nor construction ships can do anything with them. It says the gateway must be upgraded before use. How may I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gateway needs to be in your territory for you to be able to activate it. To get it activated again, you need to click on the Gateway and click the upgrade button. It costs 10,000 energy and 5,000 minerals. Gateways (as you probably know) allows connection to other gateways across the galaxy. See the gateway section [here](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/FTL#Gateways).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in 2.0, you also need to have an outpost in the gateway system before you have the option to upgrade it.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes, I believe that is true. I assumed the gateway was already in the nation's territory, but I will add that to answer.

Comment: @Steve-O This is the same as it being in your territory.

Comment: @Studoku If you check teh edit history on the answer, you'll see the bit about territory was added *after* my comment was made... And that was my point in commenting :)